# Compiling C code is drastically slower since macOS Sierra on MacBook Pro 2015

Tags: c, macos, performance, gcc, clang

Since macOS Sierra, compiling C code with clang or gcc is really, really slow.
Reinstalling El Capitan (even today) solves the issue.
Building on GNU/Linux is much faster.
Building on Windows AND on WSL is also much faster.

By slower, I mean twice (or more) the time to build a simple C project. (from 5-6 seconds to 15 seconds)

For information, I tested mainly with gcc-9 and clang-10 with my school projects.
I also used tcc 0.9.27, built from source, with a dummy make+C project, see below.

I am not sure about what to do, have anybody ecountered this ?

Moreover, the whole system is really slower and sluggish since Sierra, I really think that it is a macOS issue. Other OSes are still fast.

I need macOS for the iOS/tvOS toolchain, therefore I cannot switch.
Switching to a GNU/Linux distro would be nice if I could.

If anybody needs more specific data, do not hesitate.
Many thanks for your help !

---

Things I tested **always on the same computer** with this dummy repo [edrflt/build_speed](https://github.com/edrflt/build_speed) :

**tcc 0.9.27, built from source**

*Ubuntu 20.04 (fast):*

```
make -j5   0,94s user 0,53s system 342% cpu 0,428 total
```

*Mac OS X Yosemite 10.10 (fast):*

```
make -j5   1,84s user 1,05s system 284% cpu 1,016 total
```

*Mac OS X El Capitan 10.11 (fast):*

```
make -j5   3,04s user 1,18s system 316% cpu 1,332 total
```

*macOS Catalina 10.15 (slow):*

```
make -j5   6,01s user 3,35s system 193% cpu 4,827 total
```

**gcc-9**

*Ubuntu 20.04 - gcc 9.3.0 from apt*

```
make -j5  10,15s user 4,69s system 361% cpu 4,111 total
make -j5  10,13s user 4,74s system 357% cpu 4,162 total
make -j5  10,27s user 4,54s system 359% cpu 4,119 total
```

*macOS Catalina 10.15 - gcc 9.3.0 from brew*

```
make -j5  13,95s user 10,55s system 298% cpu 8,204 total
make -j5  16,91s user 12,81s system 252% cpu 11,752 total
make -j5  14,05s user 10,81s system 295% cpu 8,412 total
```

---

Notes :

My MacBook Pro is this one :
MacBook Pro (Retina 13, early 2015) - MacBookPro12,1
i5 5257U - 8GB

I am totally open to any tests, any suggestion.
I know I don't know enough about low level OS components and compilers, therefore if you have the time, explain me like I'm five.
I will take any time that would be needed.
This is not at all about macOS is better, GNU/Linux is better ... no no, this is about "I want my computer to get his speed back".

Comment: If Ubuntu runs on the same hardware, why don't you switch entirely to it? In other words, why do you need MacOSX? Consider editing your question to improve it. Give also the *exact* version of GCC and of Clang

Comment: Beside @BasileStarynkevitch, a `gcc --verbose` can say the exact default optimization flags to the internal compiler backend (`cc1`), they can influence also the compilation time a lot. (Btw, also I did not remove the OSX from my Macbook, but I would use it only under force.)

Comment: I need macOS for the iOS/tvOS toolchain, therefore I cannot switch.  
I also kind of want to use this OS for its apps and environment.  
I tried GCC 9, clang 10.

Comment: IMNSHO and past experience (from the previous century), MacBook are not worth their money. You pay really *a lot* for the apple logo.... (and Apple stockholders) I always preferred a PC laptop under Linux.... (My first Linux experience was 1993). They don't have that sexy apple logo on the back, but they are cheaper and more reliable. YMMV

Comment: I had a Macbook G4 in 2004. It broke (physically) one month after end of warranty (so 13 months after I bought it). This is the *only* laptop computer I ever had that broke that quickly. Since then, I always bought PCs with some Linux on it.

Comment: I got the computer as a present five years ago, while I agree, I don't think I would throw the computer out. For now, I would like to understand how macOS could become that slow on this specific computer, if people have the same problem and if somebody who knows enough can help with that. I am totally open to any tests, any suggestion. I know I don't know enough about low level OS components and compilers, therefore if you have the time, explain me like I'm five, I will take any time that would be needed.

Comment: Anyway my next computer sure won't be anything from Apple. But as long I can make this one work the most I can, I will try to keep on this.

Comment: I updated the subject. I hope I am more clear now ! I would be glad to improve it more.

Comment: This seems to be becoming an argument about the merits of macOS vs Linux. Why argue? Good stuff often takes longer to make. Slow-roasted lamb versus beefburgers? Does a 15 second build really matter versus a 7 second build? Surely you measure twice and cut once. Just my 2 pence.

Comment: Actually this is not a matter of seconds, but a matter of everything is really slower on this mac. Firefox is sluggish, all apps are laggy, streaming does not work well... I chose to measure build time because I thought it would be a good benchmark or idk, maybe you have better ideas about this ? I would add that this seems to be about ONLY this mac model, 2014 ones, 15 inches 2015 ones are not affected... and this is not my computer, I recommended this model to a friend and he has the exact same problem now ...

Comment: Since the issue seems to be systemwide rather than specific to programming tools, it is probably a better question for http://apple.stackexchange.com instead of SO.

Comment: Thanks, I'll see there. I thought programming experts would have an idea though.